# Avoiding inline functions in React: How to bind functions with arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, bind

I'm trying to follow the [no-bind](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md) rule for React using the pattern that they have recommended with ES6 classes:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._onClick}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
  _onClick() {
    // Do whatever you like, referencing "this" as appropriate
  }
}
```

However, when I need to pass arguments in to `_onClick`, what needs to change?

I've tried something like:

```
import {someFunc} from 'some/path';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this, a, b);
  }
  render() {
    const {
     prop1,
     prop2
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div onClick={this._onClick(prop1, prop2}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
  _onClick = (a, b) => {
    someFunc(a, b);
  }
}
```

However, this does not work. What needs to be altered?

Comment: I do not know React, but my guess would be that if the arguments are already bound then the handler should remain unchanged: `<div onClick={this._onClick}>`

Answer (score 8):

The call to `bind` in the constructor should only pass `this` as a single argument.

```
this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
```

Here you are overwriting the property `this._onClick` with a new one that has the correct `this` bound. If your function takes two arguments, then you should pass those as normal at call time.

Passing additional arguments to `bind` means that the function returned already has those arguments supplied - in your attempt the `_onClick` function will always have its first two arguments `undefined`, as `a` and `b` have no value in the constructor.

Now that you have bound `this` to your function, you can access `this.props` from within there, rather than having to pass arguments:

```
import {someFunc} from 'some/path';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._onClick}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
  _onClick() {
    const {
     prop1,
     prop2
    } = this.props;
    someFunc(prop1, prop2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use `partial application`. Basically you initialise your onClick function with the parameters you want, and the onClick function will return a new function to be called when the div is clicked.

```
import {someFunc} from 'some/path';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._onClick(prop1, prop2)}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
  _onClick = (a, b) => {
    return () => someFunc(a, b);
  }
}
```

PS: this only applies if your parameters `a` and `b` are not part of your `this.props`, if they are then you should just do as `Tom Fenech` said.

Comment: This solution is totally wrong. It just prevents the ESLint warning. But the problem of creating a new function on every render is still there delegated to an intermediary function. EDIT: since this merge (https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1444) this solution not even prevents the warning.

Comment: This is a very bad solution in terms of optimization! _onClick here returns a new function each time. Even if two functions have the same function definition, they will fail the equality test since two separate objects are never equal

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question there is nothing special you have to do in order to pass arguments to your `this._onClick` function.

the proper revised code will be:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this._onClick(1, 2)}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
  _onClick = (a, b) => {
    console.log(a, b);
  }
}
```

Secondly, the way you are calling `this._onClick` is not the right way to invoke a function on `click`.

Right now what is happening that on each render process your function is getting called because you didn't pass the function as an argument rather you invoked that function and assigned its returned value to the onClick prop.

you have to do this like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => this._onClick(prop1, prop2)}>
      Hello!
    </div>
  );
}
```

By Invoking your function this way you ensure the `this._onClick` will get called when click event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use Babel stage 1 autobind and skip the constructor.

```js
import {someFunc} from 'some/path';

class Foo extends React.Component {
  _onClick = () => {
    const {
     prop1,
     prop2
    } = this.props;
    someFunc(prop1, prop2);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this._onClick}>
        Hello!
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```